# How to get a layered aligning of maps

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

Say I want to illustrate a map based on the form:

[image]

EXCEPT I want to continue this 'step' structure:

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A: B &\to C \\
  b &\mapsto c : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As I stated I want to get a step structure to continue the steps in form of this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A: B &\to C \\
  b &\mapsto c : &&V \to \mathbb U\\
 &&v\mapsto u: &&&X \to Y \\ 
 &&&x \mapsto y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but unfortunately this only delivers

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `alignat*` for that, because it inserts no space between the alignment columns, unless you specify one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A: B &\longrightarrow C \\
  b &\longmapsto c : {}&V&\longrightarrow \mathbb U\\
 &&v & \longmapsto u:{} &X & \longrightarrow Y \\
 &&& & x & \longmapsto y
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]